# In Azure Devops, how can i use pipeline variables in a "Azure CLI task v.2" running shell script?

Tags: bash, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

I am trying to execute a task using Azure CLI and **bash** in Azure Devops. I am using **Azure CLI task v.2** and choosing ***shell*** as script type as below.
[image]
I want to use pipeline variables in bash script. I run the command below inside the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
az role assignment create --role "Lab Admin" --assignee $(ownerEmail) -g $(rgName)
```

and i got the error below:

```
 line 2: ownerEmail: command not found
 line 2: rgName: command not found
```

I don't understand. Normally, i should be able to use azure cli in a bash script.
Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could read the pipeline variables in your bash script:

1. (Suggested) Read them straight as environment variables in the script. Azure DevOps pipeline variables are added as environment variables that can be accessed by your bash script. So just by defining/setting the pipeline variables you can access them from the bash script. i.e in your script reference them as $OWNERNAME and $RGNAME.
   See > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables#environment-variables
2. Reference the direct argument in the bash script. Bash arguments are numbered and can be referenced as such. e.g for your aruments $1 is the string "-labOwner" $2 is the value contained within the ownerEmail pipeline variable.
   See > https://tecadmin.net/tutorial/bash-scripting/bash-command-arguments/

Answer (score 11):

Variables are passed in as environment variables. The variables are all uppercased and case-sensitive on linux.

Thus, `$OWNERNAME` and `$RGNAME` are likely the values you're after.

See the section on variable usage in scripts:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#environment-variables

There are some tasks that don't populate the environment at all, these have an **environment** section where you can manually pass in the environment variables.